# Bunyan stream takes 100% cpu when target is down

Tags: node.js, redis, bunyan

I'm using "[bunyan-redis](https://github.com/harrisiirak/bunyan-redis)" (already posyted an issue there) in order to send all my logs to a redis broker.

When the redis broker got full and couldn't accept more input logs, the node app started working at 100% CPU, and couldn't accept any requests.

How can I disable this dependency between the logs to the node activity?
I don't want that any logger problems will cause the app to stop reacting.

Nodejs 0.10.25
running on a "c4.large" EC2 machine